# How to add days to the current date?

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

I am trying to add days to the current date and it's working fine but when I add 360 days to the current date it gives me wrong value.

eg: Current Date is 11/04/2014

And I am adding 360 Days to it, it should give me 11/04/2015, but it is showing the same date 11/04/2014. the year is not changing.

Here is my code:

```
select dateadd(dd,360,getdate())
```

Comment: Why should it return `11/04/2015`? Correct would be `2015-04-06 15:00:00` and indeed i get this result. But you can add a year instead of 360 days: `select dateadd(year,1,getdate())`

Comment: But i am not getting this value..

Comment: i have to add days not a year.

Comment: `dateadd(dd,360,getdate())` is giving me `2015-04-06`

Comment: If you do `select getdate(), dateadd(dd, 360, getdate())`, you get two identical values ?

Comment: The value you're expecting (11/04/2015) is 365 days (a year) from today.

Comment: Way late to the party, I know, but this sounds a bit suspicious.  The 360 vs 365 thing, for one.  Another is that it's returning today's date.  @RaphaëlAlthaus has a valid question.

Answer (score 63):

Just do-

```
Select (Getdate()+360) As MyDate
```

There is no need to use dateadd function for adding or subtracting days from a given date. For adding years, months, hours you need the dateadd function.

Comment: Poor code as it is not explicit. dateadd(dd,360,getdate()) makes it more obvious (and you rely on the internal implementation of a datetime), though this may be part of the SQL standard I didn't think it was.

Comment: DateAdd should be used instead of +/- operators on dates. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29696475/354756

Answer (score 38):

`select dateadd(dd,360,getdate())` will give you correct date as shown below:

> 2017-09-30 15:40:37.260

I just ran the query and checked:
[image: Please check the attached image]

Answer (score 29):

```
Dateadd(datepart,number,date)
```

You should use it like this:

```
select DATEADD(day,360,getdate())
```

Then you will find the same date but different year.

Answer (score 12):

From the SQL Server 2017 [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 360, GETDATE());
```

If you would like to **remove the time part** of the `GETDATE` function, you can do:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 360, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008 and above just do this:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Getdate()) AS DateAdd;
```

Answer (score 1):

can try this

```
select (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()+360,110)) as Date_Result
```

Comment: DateAdd should be used instead of +/- operators on dates. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29696475/354756

Answer (score 1):

Two or three ways (depends what you want), say we are at Current Date is 
(in tsql code) -

```
DECLARE @myCurrentDate datetime = '11Apr2014 10:02:25 AM'
```

(BTW - did you mean 11April2014 or 04Nov2014 in your original post? hard to tell, as datetime is culture biased. In Israel 11/04/2015 means 11April2014. I know in the USA 11/04/2014 it means 04Nov2014. tommatoes tomatos I guess)

1. `SELECT @myCurrentDate + 360` - by default datetime calculations followed by + (some integer), just add that in days. So you would get `2015-04-06 10:02:25.000` - not exactly what you wanted, but rather just a ball park figure for a close date next year.
2. `SELECT DateADD(DAY, 365, @myCurrentDate)` or `DateADD(dd, 365, @myCurrentDate)` 
   will give you '2015-04-11 10:02:25.000'. These two are syntatic sugar (exacly the same). This is what you wanted, I should think. But it's still wrong, because if the date was a "3 out of 4" year (say     `DECLARE @myCurrentDate datetime = '11Apr2011 10:02:25 AM'`) you would get '2012-04-10 10:02:25.000'. because 2012 had 366 days, remember? (29Feb2012 consumes an "extra" day. Almost every fourth year has 29Feb).
3. So what I think you meant was

   ```
   SELECT DateADD(year, 1, @myCurrentDate)
   ```

   which gives `2015-04-11 10:02:25.000`.
4. or better yet

   ```
   SELECT DateADD(year, 1, DateADD(day, DateDiff(day, 0, @myCurrentDate), 0))
   ```

   which gives you `2015-04-11 00:00:00.000` (because datetime also has time, right?). Subtle, ah?

Answer (score 1):

Add Days in Date in SQL

```
 DECLARE @NEWDOB DATE=null
 
 SET @NEWDOB= (SELECT DOB, DATEADD(dd,45,DOB)AS NEWDOB FROM tbl_Employees)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give total number of days including today in the current month.

```
select day(getDate())
```

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT DateAdd(5,day(getdate())` this is for adding 5 days to current days.
for eg:today date is 23/08/2018 it became 28/08/2018 by using the above query