# Add Additional Day SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I add an additional day to this?

```
,Cast([real_dd] as Date) Delivery_Date
```

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,@Date)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add days to the current date in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013277/how-to-add-days-to-the-current-date-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You would use `dateadd()`:

```
select dateadd(day, 1, cast(read_dd as date)) as delivery_date
```